# html helpers text input and line break

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, html-helper, line-breaks

```
public string BannerText {get;set;}

public void SetBanner()
{
  BannerText = "This is line 1. \nThis is line 2."
}
```

in the aspx page I am setting it like this:

```
<div>
  <h1><%: Model.BannerText %></h1>
</div>
```

However, the text still shows up in a single line. I have tried `<br />` and `<br>` as well but that doesn't seem to work.  I am sure it has to be something simple, but need SO help :)

EDIT:Kirk Woll and Mike suggestion worked! 
use: `<h1><%= Model.BannerText %></h1>`

Comment: That looks fine to me...  In your real code (assuming that is simplified) are you sure ClientName is set when you assign BannerText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "`<%:`"?  I haven't seen that before.  Have you tried "`<%=`"?  That will use an HTMLTextWriter to pass the string to render.  Then just use HTML (`<br />`) in your string.

Answer (score 2):

First, `\n` will absolutely not work.  This is HTML.   You do need to use `<br />` (or wrap them in `<div>`, etc.).  However, the purpose of `<%:` (as opposed to `<%=`) is to HTML-encode your string.  So presumably your line breaks (`<br />`) are being encoded.   You should try `<%=` instead and see if that fixes your issue.